# Programmatically add workbook event and save it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of excel files in a spreadsheet.  I'd like to loop through them and add a worksheet event to each.  Save it, close it and move on to the next.  The problem is that when I reopen (manually) the workbook the code is gone.

Inside the for each loop:

```
Set xl = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
addCode xl 'subroutine to add code
xl.Save
xl.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

The addCode subroutine is:

```
Sub addCode(book As Excel.Workbook)
     acsh = book.ActiveSheet.CodeName
     startline = book.VBProject.VBComponents(acsh).CodeModule.CreateEventProc("SelectionChange", "Worksheet") + 1
     book.VBProject.VBComponents(acsh).CodeModule.InsertLines startline, codetoadd
End Sub
```

If I comment out xl.Close the code is in the workbook and works.  I can manually save and close the file and the code remains.  I've added a break point between xl.save and xl.close and made a copy of the file.  After the code is done neither has the changes.  I've tried using xl.saveas and xl.close SaveChanges:=True.  All have identical results.

I'm using Excel 2013, I've told excel to trust access to the VBA object model.  I've tried using XLS files and XLSM files.  Obviously XLSX won't work.

Comment: It sounds like Excel doesn't recognise that the file is *dirty*, so the Save doesn't think there's anything to do? Have you tried adding a line that changes some other property before saving? That might prompt Excel to consider the file dirty.

Comment: The *dirty* flag is here: `ThisWorkbook.Saved = False` (readable and writeable). Yet, I don't think that's the problem. Are the workbooks you are opening `.xlsx` or are they `.xlsm`? If they are `.xlsx` then all VBA code gets automatically cut off. Yet, normally an alert would be shown that all code will get removed (while attempting to save the file).

Comment: I just added xl.saved = false before the save, same problem.  It was updating the modified file date/time so I assume it's been saving all along.  I've used xlsm and xls, I don't expect xlsx to work so never tried.

Comment: Was the file an .xlsm to start off with e.g. filepath = "C:\data\sheet.xlsm" ?

Comment: @Robin yes.  I've tried xls->xls, xlsm->xlsm, xls->xlsm and xlsx->xlsm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code which is working for me on Excel 2010. The changes I made to your example code are:

- use a .xlsm for the target workbook - I know you said you already did that.
- reference a specific worksheet in the AddCode sub rather than pick up the sheet name from ActiveSheet.
- set the workbook dirty status per Ralph's comment
- Don't set the SaveChanges flag when closing the target workbook

Other than that, my version is pretty similar to yours. I think it is the `wb.Saved = False` line that does the trick i.e. the dirty flag. I tried to use the `SaveAs` method on the `VBProject` itself thinking it would be the same as hitting the save button when you are in the VBA Editor itself. However, this just gives unhelpful errors.

Here's the sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim strCode As String

    ' get target workbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("\\server\path\Book3.xlsm")

    ' test setting code to worksheet change
    strCode = "Debug.Print ""Sheet selection changed to: "" & Target.Address"
    AddWorksheetChangeCode wbTarget, "Sheet1", strCode

    ' test saving the target workbook
    With wbTarget
        ' set book to dirty to force the save
        .Saved = False
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

End Sub

Sub AddWorksheetChangeCode(ByRef wb As Workbook, strWorksheetName As String, strCode As String)

    Dim intInsertLine As Integer

    ' create stub for event and get line to insert
    intInsertLine = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(strWorksheetName).CodeModule.CreateEventProc("SelectionChange", "Worksheet") + 1

    ' add event logic
    wb.VBProject.VBComponents(strWorksheetName).CodeModule.InsertLines intInsertLine, strCode

End Sub
```

Comment: First I tried your code, works, perfect!  Then I tried to figure out why.  The save flag (on .close) and the .saved=false don't seem to be important.

As soon as I changed acsh="Sheet1" from book.ActiveSheet.CodeName it worked.  I tried inside of the sub and passing into the sub every time it worked if it was hard coded, didn't work otherwise.  The thing I'm failing to understand is why, because book.ActiveSheet.CodeName is "Sheet1" (I've checked).

One thing for anyone else who tries to use the code.  VBComponents() takes the code name which may or may not be the same as the sheet name.